# Gnome 3 Software Center

Tags: fedora, package-management, gnome3

Just installed Fedora 15 with Gnome 3. Is there like a software center like in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

You can find it under `Applications->System Tools->Add/remove software` menu item; the features are searching for package names, application titles or description, and package groups.
Alternatively, you could install `yumex`.

Fedora pkgdb is also a good source of information:
https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb

Comment: Yes I found that but it can't find hos to add repositories, is it possible? Will try yumex and check out the link! Thanks!

Comment: @tbleckert: within add/remove software->file->software sources you can only *select* which software repositories you intend to use (beware fiddling too much with repositories as you could generate orphans or maybe a dependecies hell). To add a repo you can start by installing the setup rpm from the repository website (ie. http://www.rpmfusion.org/) or editing or creating by hand the files under /etc/yum.repos.d (youll need to be root).